# GitlabCI - Difference between include local and template

Tags: gitlab-ci

There is an example like that in their [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-nested-includes):

```yaml
include:
  - template: defaults.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: unit-tests.gitlab-ci.yml
  - local: smoke-tests.gitlab-ci.yml
```

What is the difference between `local` and `template` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) :

- [local](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includelocal) : Use `include:local` to include a file that is in the same repository as the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.
- [template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includetemplate) : Use `include:template` to include [.gitlab-ci.yml templates](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/tree/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates).

So they don't have the same goal, `local` is used to include some files from the current repository and `template` is used to include some Gitlab templates.

Comment: Is there just a difference of location... or do the file also have a **different (type of) content** ?

Comment: Just difference of location, the `template` keyword allow you to include some Gitlab templates directly without using the `remote` keyword.